# Proxy Internet problem on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

We have proxy Internet at college and I can not access it on Ubuntu. It works on browsers but it doesn't work for any other application like the Ubuntu software center. I tried to apply the network proxy settings system wide and it doesn't work. It gives this error:

```
Failed to download the repository information
Check your Internet connection
```

Using `172.16.0.2` with `8080` with user name and password. 
 They use [Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Forefront_Threat_Management_Gateway) for proxy server.
help !

Comment: We need to know: 1. What is your proxy-adress and port? 2. do you use authentication like username and password on it? 3. What kind of network are you connected to? Explain briefly.

Comment: @denNorske i have just added the information you required :)

Comment: I'll make an answer for you, hang on for 2 hours - busy now.

Comment: @denNorske ok 2 hours :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

The contents are, after applying the proxy "system wide":

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://172.16.0.2:8080/";
```

But, in order to make this work, you must add your username and password into it:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080/";
```

Save the file and you are good to go to install things from both terminal and Software-center :P

(Note that the proxy will only work on internet-browsers and software-center/terminal with apt-get)

Comment: No problem, glad i could help!

Comment: Isn't there any secure way to put the password there because its readable to anyone who can access that file ?