# Problem in wifi connectivity- each time need to fill proxy

Tags: 12.10, wireless, proxy, system-settings

Each time, I have to fill in the network settings again and again on my Ubuntu 12.10 and also it is not showing the  the "apply system wide " option

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf`
and add the proxy

---

`Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy-adress:port/";`
`Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://proxy-adress:port/";`
`Acquire::https::proxy "https://proxy-adress:port/";`
for example: `Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.168.1.1:8080/";`

---

and if you have user name and password then do this

---

`Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@proxy-adress/";`
`Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@proxy-adress/";`
`Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@proxy-adress/";`

for Example: `Acquire::https::proxy "https://abcd:123456@proxy-adress/";`

Check that answer hopefully it will help you too.
[Proxy Internet problem on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354666/proxy-internet-problem-on-ubuntu)